# python-twitter not accepting strings that are < 140 char with no links

Tags: python-2.7, python-twitter

I'm working on a home automation project that uses [`python-twitter`](http://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to post update information. When I try to post a shorter-than-140 string with no links, I end up getting a `TwitterError: Text must be less than or equal to 140 characters.`

Here's some shell output describing the problem:

```
>>> import twitter
>>> api = twitter.Api(
...     consumer_key=os.environ['TW_API_KEY'],
...     consumer_secret=os.environ['TW_API_SECRET'],
...     access_token_key=os.environ['TW_ACCESS_KEY'],
...     access_token_secret=os.environ['TW_ACCESS_SECRET']
...     )
>>> m = 'The house is now inside the comfort range. Conditions: 28.4 C (83.1 F) at 50.0% humidity. It feels like 84 F.'
>>> len(m)
109
>>> api.PostUpdate(m)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/site/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twitter/api.py", line 952, in PostUpdate
    raise TwitterError("Text must be less than or equal to 140 characters.")
TwitterError: Text must be less than or equal to 140 characters.
```

I tried converting the string to unicode using `api.PostUpdate(u'{0}'.format(m))` but unsurprisingly no help there either.

I assume what's happening is that `python-twitter` is interpreting the decimal numbers as links, thereby decreasing the amount of characters I have left to use, but I don't know enough about the api to know if that's true or not.

Given that I am not planning on including links in these tweets, is there a way to force `python-twitter` to ignore the decimals without actually getting rid of them? I would prefer not to settle for that workaround, as I kind of like being able to report in decimal notation. I would also prefer not to have to go with [`tweepy`](http://www.tweepy.org/) but I suppose I'd swallow that pill if I needed to.

**Update:** I've found a way to turn off the api's length check using the `verify_status_length=False` flag in [`PostUpdate()`](http://python-twitter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/twitter.html#twitter.api.Api.PostUpdate), which allows me to tweet the above string `m` with no errors. It doesn't feel that elegant but I will stick with it for now until I find a better solution.

Comment: Please post the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Comment: @MattDMo I don't see why it's necessary as I am working in the console, but there you are.